# Applying a discount code to a specific product in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I've been working on setting up a Shopify store. One major feature they don't have built in is being able to provide a discount to a specific product, even though it looks like people have been requesting it since 2008!

Does anyone have any idea how this could be accomplished with their API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Shopify API doesn’t offer product-specific discounts yet. It’s definitely in the pipe, but the feature is not available yet.

Comment: As of July 29th update, this feature is now included in Shopify: 
http://www.shopify.com/blog/3715012-new-feature-individual-product-and-collection-discounts

Comment: Yesterday I added 1000 Discount codes to a shop, assigned to a mix of products, discount values and expiry dates using a Ruby script. Clearly it is easy to work with Shopify Discount Codes.

Comment: Hey @DavidLazar, I just combed through the API docs (http://api.shopify.com/) and didn't read anything regarding Discount codes. Could you offer up some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Chuck. Discount Codes are NOT in the API at this time. You can script them for sure using Mechanize or some other form submission machine if you want.

Comment: @DavidLazar Thanks for the followup David. I may have to do just that.

Answer (score 3):

Shopify allows you to offer product-specific discounts. On your Shopify Admin / Dashboard go to Discounts. Click on Add a discount:

[image]

On the Discount type section make sure to choose the Specific product from the dropdown:

[image]

Click on Save and you're all set. On your discounts list you'll see the generated discount with the conditions along with the product name:

[image]